# Conditionally replace list elements with values from shorter list

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to simply replace the values of a list when they meet a condition with values from a shorter list.

For example:

```
list1 = [1,0,1,0,1,0]
list2 = [1,2,3]
```

The output I want is:

```
list1 = [1,1,1,2,1,3]
```

I can use a loop with a counter:

```
counter = 0
for i, j in enumerate(list1):
    if j == 1:
        list1[i] = list2[counter]
        counter += 1
```

But this seems inefficient for something so simple, so I'm guessing there might be a way to do this with a list comprehension, something like:

```
[list2[i] if j == 0 else j for i,j in enumerate(list1)]
```

(although this fails due the lists being different lengths).

Is there any other concise way of doing this in base python, perhaps using `map` or `filter`?

Comment: Shorter code isn't necessarily more efficient code. Unless this is for a code golf challenge, I'm failing to see what's wrong with the solution you have.

Comment: Good point, I suppose it's just because I use this type of operation a lot in other languages (where you can just use logical indexing), and I'm looking for something similar in terms of ease of typing.

Answer (score 7):

You can use an iterator made from the short list and just call [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on it in the comprehension:

```
list1 = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]

it2 = iter(list2)

[x if x != 0 else next(it2) for x in list1]
# [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Note that you can provide a default value to [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) if there are not enough filler elements:

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
[x if x else list2.pop(0) for x in list1]
```

Note this removes items from `list2`.

Comment: While this works, you should note that every `pop(0)` is `O(N)`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Nice catch.

Comment: I guess you could reverse the list beforehand, and then call `pop()`. But then reversing a list is `O(N)`, which shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @RoadRunner except as written it does `O(n)` `O(n)` pops, so it's `O(n^2)`. Reversing it first reduces that complexity to `O(n)` + `O(n)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
list1 = [1,0,1,0,1,0]
list2 = [1,2,3]
new_list = [list2[list1[:i].count(a)] if a != 1 else a for i, a in enumerate(list1)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map), you could try this:

```
from collections import deque

list1 = [1,0,1,0,1,0]
list2 = [1,2,3]

queue = deque(list2)

result = list(map(lambda x : x if x else queue.popleft(), list1))

print(result)
```

Which outputs:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
```

**Note:** I used a stack/queue data structure, [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to allow a `O(1)` `popleft()` from the front, instead of using `pop(0)`, which is `O(n)`. If you don't wish to use this library, you can just reverse `list2` beforehand, and call `pop()`, which is also `O(1)`.